# Subfield of splitting field is a splitting field of some polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Exercise from Cox's book Galois Theory.

> Let $F \subset L$ be the splitting field of $f(x) \in F[x]$, and let $K$ be a field such that $F \subset K \subset L$. Prove that $L$ is the splitting field of some polynomial in $K[x]$.

So let $\alpha_i$ be the roots of $f(x)$ in $L$. Then I'm guessing I need to show that $L$ has the form $K(\alpha_{i_1}, \dots, \alpha_{i_m})$, and then conclude that $L$ is the splitting field of a polynomial like $g(x)= c(x-\alpha_{i_1}) \dots (x- \alpha_{i_m})$. But how can I show that $L$ has the form I want, and also how can I be sure that $g(x)$ has coefficients in $K$?

Comment: Fixed a typo that seems to have sent you off in the wrong direction -- it's $L$, not $K$, that is a splitting field. Now maybe you can solve it on your own?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Your edit improved the situation a lot. But the title still reflects the original misunderstanding. While any answerer should read the actual question, the original title may be a magnet to users wanting to cry "False!" Having said that, I'm not 100% sure that editing the title to match the question is prudent, because it seems to be exactly what the asker has/had trouble with. <insert headache emoticon here>

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Oops, I never look at the title for some reason...

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I have totally misread the question. In that case, isn't $f(x)$ the answer? Since $f(x) \in K[x]$ and $L$ is the smallest field which contains all roots of $f(x)$.